# IE8 is not recognizing my regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to parse an AJAX response and get the id of the body tag. I can't do this via jQuery, though, because jQuery can't emulate a DOM response for a body tag.

I've split this into many lines to try and isolate the error. This works in modern browsers, but it's failing in IE8.

```
var bodyIDregex = new RegExp(/<body[^>]*id=["'](.*?)["']>/gi),
matched = html.match(bodyIDregex),
bodyID = bodyIDregex.exec(matched[0]);
bodyID = bodyID[1];
```

I have confirmed that the value of the variable html is as expected.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: In addition to what Asad said, my guess is this has something to do with the "g" flag and your sequence of first calling `.match(regex)` and then calling `regex.exec()` with the same regex.  The "g" flag can leave state in the regular expression because `.exec` can be called multiple times to yield successive matches.  I'd suggest that you use a different regular  expression for the `.match()` call (probably without the "g" flag).  I could verify this was the case if you included sample text you're matching against, but without that, we are just guessing.

Comment: @paulsm4: Wrong. jQuery is indeed faulty in that way, it cannot parse full HTML documents. And there are many more things that jQuery was not even designed to do…

Comment: It'd be interesting to see if jQuery could parse the body tag if it were set to interpret the results as an XML document rather than an HTML document... but to be honest, I'm not sure if that would work either. Of course, the limitation there would be that you would have to have an HTML document that is valid XML (XHTML). And I write in HTML5, sometimes without closing slash, etc. required for an XML doc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should either pass a string to the constructor for regexen, *or* use the regex literal syntax, but not both.

```
var bodyIDregex = /<body[^>]*id=["'](.*?)["']>/gi
```

or

```
var bodyIDregex = new RegExp("<body[^>]*id=[\"'](.*?)[\"']>","gi")
```

**Update:**

As you have correctly identified in your answer, the problem stems from the fact that the regex search continues from the position of the last character in the previous match. One way to correct this is to reset `lastIndex`, but in this case this is not required, since you only need to match against the string once:

```
var bodyIDregex = /<body[^>]*id=["'](.*?)["']>/gi,
    bodyID = bodyIDregex.exec(html);

//bodyID is now the array, ["<body id="test">asdf</body>", "test"]

alert(bodyID[1]);
//alerts the captured group, "test"
```

Comment: Good to know, thanks! Unfortunately, it doesn't resolve my error, which still says that 1 is null or not an object.

Comment: @MMiller That is odd indeed. That would mean IE8 doesn't include captured groups as an entry in the matches array. Could you post the exact text of the error?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of a test on WriteCodeOnline.com (I guess JSfiddle doesn't work in IE8?). https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28836420/ie8.png

Comment: @MMiller Why are you executing the regex on the original string twice?

Comment: You know what? I have no idea why I was. Shows what happens when I try to play with regular expressions.... Thanks!

Comment: I actually just had an instance where I did need to run a regex on a string multiple times (it was being modified) and lastIndex was the exact issue killing IE8. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, when you call (RegExp object).match(string), it increments a property of the RegExp object called lastIndex. I am not completely familiar with how the RegExp object works, but this causes an issue when trying to call the exec() method later.

The solution, apparently, is to reset lastIndex to zero.

```
var html = '<html><body id="test">asdf</body></html>';

var bodyIDregex = /<body[^>]*id=["'](.*?)["']>/gi,
matched = html.match(bodyIDregex);
// Reset lastIndex
bodyIDregex.lastIndex = 0;
var bodyID = bodyIDregex.exec(matched[0]);
alert(bodyID.length);
bodyID = bodyID[1];

document.write(bodyID); // writes test
```

Comment: I've updated my answer with an approach to solving the problem.