# Issue with Regular expression in IE

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer

I have a problem in all versions of Internet Explorer with regular expressions. I get the error ”invalid syntax for regular expression”. It works fine in all other browsers including Microsoft Edge. While debugging in IE I noticed that it strips out ”/” in the beginning from the regex. Why does it do that?

```
var pattern = /^\d{10}$/;

function isPattern(input, pattern) {
    if (typeof pattern === "string") {
        pattern = "^" + pattern + "$";
    }
    var rePattern = new RegExp( pattern, "i" );
    return (typeof input === "string" && rePattern.test( input ));
}
```

I suspect that the error is because in Explorer it removes the first "/" from regex.

Comment: Which version of IE are you referring to? Please add some more code too, so we can see how exactly you're using the regex.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove `"i"` from `var rePattern = new RegExp( pattern, "i" );`

Actually, You should either pass a string to the constructor for regexen, or use the regex literal syntax, but not both.

```
var pattern = /^\d{10}$/i
```

or

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^\d{10}$","i")
```

Refer here - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721057/ie8-is-not-recognizing-my-regular-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721057/ie8-is-not-recognizing-my-regular-expression])